Confused about including the inclusive
As an English literature lover, I am confused trying to write in English according to the new inclusive language, for example :  "he speaks French quite like a french man but speaks about France better than a french man".
How would you put it to involve ALL the french and not just "men" ?
Thank you for all the suggestions...

"he speaks French quite like all French people..."
or "he speaks French quite like any French person..."
